# PHP read php file output and use it as a string

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents

Currently i use a file to dynamically produce a sql string depening on the value passed in the URL

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/for.php?passenger='.$user_id.'&seat='.$nos.'&seatstatus=BP&coach='.$noc.'&date='.$date.'');
$file_result = $db->query($file);
if($file_result->num_rows>0){
//Do Somthing
}
```

however when i use this method the output is nothing however when i

```
echo $file;
```

it appears correctly

if i pass `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/for2.php?passenger=32&seat=4&seatstatus=BP&coach=1&date=2015-04-30`

then the SQL produced is

```
"SELECT * FROM `Events` WHERE `Date` = '2015-04-30' and `User_1_1` = '32' and `Status_1_1` = 'BP' or `Date` = '2015-04-30' and `User_1_2` = '32' and `Status_1_2` = 'BP' or `Date` = '2015-04-30' and `User_1_3` = '32' and `Status_1_3` = 'BP' or `Date` = '2015-04-30' and `User_1_4` = '32' and `Status_1_4` = 'BP' or `Lookup` = '1'"
```

so im not quite sure what im doing incorrectly

Comment: It sounds like the SQL query is not returning any rows, Please show your SQL query.

Comment: When you echo the query, copy it, and run it directly on your database. It may simply be a case that the query doesn't return any rows :)

Comment: Lookup = '1'"` seems to be your problem. Probably Lookup = '1' is correct. Run your query and you will see that you are getting 0 results.

Comment: i have edited my question above to include the SQL

Comment: that was it @CamilStaps when it produced the SQL it also included the quotes as i was treating it as if i had not called it as a variable thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes (`"`) around the SQL. These should not be a part of the query you send to MySQL, because like this it's not valid SQL.